# jquery-multilevel dynamic form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code

```html
<form>
  <div id="vehicle">
    <input type="text" name="vehicle[]" placeholder="vehicle name">
    <div id="type[]">
      <input type="text" name="type[]" placeholder="type name">
    </div>
    <a href="#">add Type</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">delete Type</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <a href="#">add Vehicle</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">delete Vehicle</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>

</form>
```

My question is : How to make dynamic form. The rule is every vehicle allow to have many type. And I can add the vehicle with different type.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

> id="vehicle" use class for

instead of

```
<div id="type[]">
    <input type="text" name="type[]" placeholder="type name">
</div>
```

use

```
<div>
     <select name="type[]" multiple>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">800cc</option>
        <option value="2">1000cc</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

if you use select with multiple you can select one or more type

Comment: then how to add type option ?